# Set Height On a Container, After Re-sizing an Inner Element

Tags: jquery, css

My website displays a list of members.

Each list item has a photo, title (member's name) and a small excerpt.

On large screens, the list is just one row. On smaller screen, the row collapse into 3 columns and finally two columns (less than 768px).

I want each item to have an equal height, so that each 'row' (on smaller devices) contains an equal number of items.

This is a common task, for which I write a quick function which is called on $(window).load() and on $(window).resize().

The problem I'm having with this job, is (i'm assuming) to do with the fact that - before I set the height of all member items, I first set the height of an element within each member item. This inner element is the photo, which I resize every time the window is resized. (I do this because the photos must appear as circles, so I need to change each photo's height as it's width changes).

I can't determine exactly what the problem is, but I can see that the final height set on each member item is too short, and each items content overflows it's height. This happens on resizing the window, only, and does work fine on initial page load.

This is the mark up for an item (a member):

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="member">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="path/to/file.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <h3>John Smith</h3>
            <p>I like to code.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the function (which is called on window load and window resize):

```
function resizeMembers(){

    var highestMember = 0;

    $('.member').each(function(i,e){

        $(e).find('.image img').height($(e).find('.image .img').width());

        if($(e).height() > highestMember){
            highestMember = $(e).height();
        }

    });

    $('.member').each(function(i,e){

        $(e).height(highestMember);

    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the final loop is setting too low-a height on each item? I'm guessing it's something to do with the image's new height not being taken into account?

Comment: Could you possibly make a minimal example on JSFiddle?

Comment: Also, are all the images square to begin with? If so, you could simply set their height to `auto` using CSS.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Yes, they are all squares. Problem fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way around the problem.

Whether or not this constitutes as an answer, will depend on what exactly the reason is that you were searching when you found this question.

But, here is an alternative to the code in my question:

```
function resizeMembers(){
    var highestMember = 0;

    $('.member').each(function(i,e){

    $(e).find('.image .img').height($(e).find('image .img').width());

    if($(e).find('.bottom').height() > highestMember){
        highestMember = $(e).find('.bottom').height();
    }

});


$('.home-member-x').each(function(i,e){

    the_height = highestMember + $(e).find('.image').width();

    $(e).height(the_height);

});
```

}

Another suitable answer, for someone who finds this page, is as @darrylyeo pointed out - Make all the original images squares (and set height to auto for images).